# SQL UPDATE IIF ,I deleted all my rows by accident :(

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2007, iif-function

**IN MS-ACCESS:**
 I have a table `RESTAURANTS` that has a column `Price`

I want to change the prices in the table based on these conditions:

if the price is less than 25, add 10 to that price, if the price is 25 or over, I want to subtract 10 from that price. This is the syntax I used:

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS
SET Price = IIF(Price <25, Price= Price +10, Price = Price -10)
```

PROBLEM: Instead of changing the prices, I deleted them all

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS SET Price = IIF(Price <25, Price +10, Price -10)
```

What you did is supply the *full expression* as the argument, which I think ended up being evaluated as a *logical* expression (always false). The *result* of the IIF is the amount you wish to increment the original price, so that's what you want to return. Hope this is helpful.